# How to combine Switch statements?

Tags: java, input, switch-statement, echo

I'm new to Java and working on a school assignment. The goal is to create a Java class that will emulate the Echo tool in unix. If I type in:

> java Echo 'i love you'

it will print:

> i love you

And then there are two command line options
`-n`: omits the trailing newline
`-e`: enables the interpretation of backslash escapes.
I also need to be able to use the -n and -e at the same time.

So far I figured out how to implement `-n` and `-e` separately. This is the code:

```
public class Echo {

    public static void main(String []args) {

        switch (args[0]) {
            case "-n":
                for (int i=1; i<args.length;i++)
                    System.out.print(args[i]);
                break;

            case "-e":
                for (int i=1; i<args.length; i++) {
                    args[i]=args[i].replace("\\t", "\t");
                    args[i]=args[i].replace("\\n","\n");
                    System.out.println(args[i]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
                System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }    
}
```

I attempted to alter the code so I am able to type in:

> java Echo -n -e 'ilove\tyou'

or

> java Echo -e -n 'ilove\tyou'

and it is not working at all. This is my attempt at it:

```
public class Echo {

    public static void main(String []args) {

        if ((args[0].equals("-n") || args[0].equals("-e")) && (args[1].equals("-e") ||args[1].equals("-n"))) {
            for (int i=2; i<args.length; i++) {
                args[i]=args[i].replace("\\t", "\t");
                args[i]=args[i].replace("\\n","\n");
                System.out.print(args[i]);
            }
        } else {
            switch (args[0]) {
                case "-n":
                    for (int i=1; i<args.length;i++)
                        System.out.print(args[i]);
                    break;
                case "-e":
                    for (int i=1; i<args.length; i++) {
                        args[i]=args[i].replace("\\t", "\t");
                        args[i]=args[i].replace("\\n","\n");
                        System.out.println(args[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
                        System.out.println(args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see some errors: args[1].equals("-e) ||args[1].equals(-n)
Does it compiles fine?

Comment: You should do it in two steps, 1st to detect flags (-n, -e) then a 2nd time to do the job according to flags (they are fun :p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to where the flags are located within `args[]` and where the string is. Since your `args[]` can be of length 1 (no flags), you can't access `args[1]` indiscriminately.

As also noted in [the comment by RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc), it's much easier to first find the flags and only later apply their effects. I assume that the flags must come before the string, therefore it is guaranteed that the string is in the last cell. From there, look backwards for the flags.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean hasE = false;
        boolean hasN = false;
        String message = args[args.length - 1];

        for (int i = args.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            switch (args[i]) {
                case "-n": hasN = true; break;
                case "-e": hasE = true; break;
            }
        }

        if (hasE)
            message = message.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\\t", "\t");
        if (hasN)
            System.out.print(message);
        else
            System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I did not do input validation (you did not mention it in your assignment or code and I don't want to do the whole assignment). Hint: check `args.length` for 0 or more than 3.
- I assume that you only need to escape tabs and newlines. If you need to escape more things then a more complex regex is needed.
- I added a print at the end to easily check the effect of `-n`.

Comment: What if no argument is passed? That will result on a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. As you correctly said, one can't access `args` indiscriminately.

Comment: @aribeiro Input validation was not mentioned by the OP in words or code and it is not encouraged to do give the complete assignment code for homework questions. Besides, you can always add more checks for situations not mentioned in the question. I added another note to my answer specifying the issue explicitly.

Comment: I applied the same principle to my answer yesterday. :)

Comment: @aribeiro Not really, your code would have thrown an NPE for *valid* input. Input validation is for *invalid* input.

Comment: I'm assuming you're still referring to "...if I insert neither `-n` or `-e`". In this case the result would be an AIOOBE not a NPE, but still the input was valid as you stated.

Comment: @aribeiro Yes, sorry, AIOOBE. Maybe I didn't understand what "*the same principle*" referred to. My point was that the OP stated that the input is 0-2 flags followed by a string. If the code doesn't work for that then it's just wrong. If the input is not that, only then validation is relevant (and was not required by the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
public class Echo {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        boolean isTrailingActive = false;
        boolean isEscapingActive = false;
        String inputStr;
        int index = 0;

        // Validates the amount of arguments passed to Echo
        if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 3) {
            return;
        }

        while (index < args.length - 1) {
            // Validates trailing active
            if (args[index].equals("-n")) {
                isTrailingActive = true;
                index++;
            }

            // Validates escaping active
            if (args[index].equals("-e")) {
                isEscapingActive = true;
                index++;
            }
        }

        inputStr = args[index];

        if (isEscapingActive) {
            inputStr = inputStr.replace("\\t", "\t").replace("\\n","\n");
        }

        if (isTrailingActive) {
            System.out.print(inputStr);
        } else {
            System.out.println(inputStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I insert neither `-n` or `-e`?

Comment: @user1803551, nice catch. Forgot the basic case.

Comment: Where is the fix then?

Comment: @user1803551, yesterday I didn't understand your point. Updated my answer.

Comment: Alright, this works now. But why do you need the 2nd loop, will it ever run more than once? Also, command line arguments can't be `null`.

Comment: @user1803551, I've already learn something today, thank you! True, no need for that loop. It's simple absurd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104179/discussion-between-aribeiro-and-user1803551).

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions:
1 ) Use an API for CommandLine, there is plenty.

2 ) Execute a foreach on your args  ... you can manage your last argurment as string to echo or build it from each args

```
boolean optionNewline = false;  
boolean optionE = false;  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(String arg : args) {
    if ("-n".equals(arg)) {
        optionNewline = true;
    }
    else if ("-e".equals(arg)) {
        optionE = true;
    }
    else {
        // TEXT
        if(sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');    //space between text part ?
        }
        sb.append(arg);
    }
} // foreach
// DO MY JOB on SB.toString();
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd do it like this:

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        if (args[0].equals("-n")){
            //-n
            if (args[1].equals("-e")) {
                //-n -e
            }
        } else if (args[0].equals("-e")) {
            //-e
            if (args[1].equals("-n")) {
                //-e -n
            }
        } else {
            //the user typed something other than -n or -e
        }
    }
}
```

To be fair, I'm not at all familar with the "Echo"-tool in Unix, so I don't know if this code helps. Note: You might want to write the code for when both "-n" and "-e" were typed in into a separate method - considering that you'll call this code twice.

Comment: This can result in a runtime exception. Please test your code.